# HTML body leaving a little space in the side

Tags: html, bootstrap-5

I was developing a virtual restaurante menu using bootstrap and i just notice that no matter what i do, my page has a little space at the right that will not be full, i used the inspect tool to see if any element was causing it but i couldn't find anything [you can see what i'm talking about in the top right corner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7rynL.jpg)

I try setting the min-width to the body but it remains the same

```
body {
min-width: fit-content;
}
```

also tried this

```
html, body { 
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 overflow: auto;
}


<body>
<nav class="navbar sticky-top navbar-dark" style="
    padding-top: 0px;" id="navbarprincipal">
    <div class="container-fluid navbarsubtitle" style="background-color: #0f1924;">
        <div class="d-flex align-items-center align-items-stretch">
            <div class="d-flex p-2 bd-highlight"><a class="schedule">Horario de atención: 9:00 a.m - 8:00 p.m</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class=" container-fluid" style="padding-bottom: 8px;">
        <div class="col-2">
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
                <div class="p-2 bd-highlight ">
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                        <img src="assets/logo.png" alt="" width="" height="" class="d-inline-block align-text-top">
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="col-8">
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
                <div class="p-2 bd-highlight "><a class="active">Carta</a></div>
                <div class="p-2 bd-highlight "><a class="headerelement">Ubicanos</a></div>
                <div class="p-2 bd-highlight "><a class="headerelement">¡Siguenos!</a></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-2">
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
                <div class="p-2 bd-highlight "><i class="bi bi-person" style="font-size: 30px; color: white;" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="bottom" title="Iniciar Sesión"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="p-2 bd-highlight "><i class="bi bi-bag" style="font-size: 30px; color: white;" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="bottom" title="Carrito de compras"></i>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
<div class="row principalbanner align-items-center">
    <div class="entregadiv" style="margin-bottom: 25px;">
        <div class="col-12" style="margin-top: 20px;">
            <h3 style="color: black;">¿Como quieres tu pedido</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
        <div class="col-12">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col ">
                    <div class="col dropdownelement">
                        <i class="bi bi-bicycle" style="font-size: 30px; color: black;"></i>
                        <p style="color: black;">Delivery</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col ">
                    <div class="dropdownelement">
                        <i class="bi bi-cursor-fill" style="font-size: 30px; color: black;"></i>
                        <p style="color: black;">Retirar</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12" style="margin-top: 10px;margin-bottom: 25px;">
            <input type="email" class="form-control " id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Ingresa tu dirección*">
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
<div class="container-fluid" style="padding-left: 8%;padding-right: 8%;">

    <hr>
    <div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
        <div class="p-2 bd-highlight"><span class="badge rounded-pill bg-danger" style="font-size: 18px;">Estamos
                cerrados hasta mañana a las 9:00 a.m</span></div>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
        <div class="p-2 bd-highlight"><a class="menucategories" href="#hamburguesa">Hamburguesas</a></div>
        <div class="p-2 bd-highlight"><a class="menucategories" href="#polloalabrasa">Pollos a la brasa</a></div>
        <div class="p-2 bd-highlight"><a class="menucategories" href="#combos">Combos</a></div>
        <div class="p-2 bd-highlight"><a class="menucategories">Bebidas</a></div>
        <div class="p-2 bd-highlight"><a class="menucategories">Guarniciones</a></div>
        <div class="p-2 bd-highlight"><a class="menucategories">Postres</a></div>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center" style="background: url(assets/banners/2.jpg);background-size:cover;height: 180px;background-position: center bottom;position: relative;">
        <div class="p-2 bd-highlight">
            <h3 class="menucategoriestitle">Hamburguesas</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" id="hamburguesa">
        <h1>Hamburguesas</h1>
        <div class="col-4">
            <div class="card mb-3" style="max-width: 540px;">
                <div class="row g-0">
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h5 class="card-title cardtitle">Hamburguesa Royal</h5>
                            <p class="card-text carddescription">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                            <p class="card-text cardprice">S/10</p>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-2"><a href="https://wa.link/b1erbu"><i class="bi bi-whatsapp"
                                            style="font-size: 30px; color: #00bb2d;"></i></a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-6"><button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Agregar al
                                        carrito</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <img src="assets/imgs/burger.jpg" class="cardimage" onclick="overlayonproduct()">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card mb-3" style="max-width: 540px;">
                <div class="row g-0">
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h5 class="card-title cardtitle">Hamburguesa Royal</h5>
                            <p class="card-text carddescription">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                            <p class="card-text cardprice">S/10</p>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-2"><a href="https://wa.link/b1erbu"><i class="bi bi-whatsapp"
                                            style="font-size: 30px; color: #00bb2d;"></i></a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-6"><button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Agregar al
                                        carrito</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <img src="assets/imgs/burger.jpg" class="cardimage">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-4">
            <div class="card mb-3" style="max-width: 540px;">
                <div class="row g-0">
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h5 class="card-title cardtitle">Hamburguesa Clasica</h5>
                            <p class="card-text carddescription">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                            <p class="card-text cardprice">S/6</p>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-2"><a href="https://wa.link/b1erbu"><i class="bi bi-whatsapp"
                                            style="font-size: 30px; color: #00bb2d;"></i></a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-6"><button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Agregar al
                                        carrito</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <img src="assets/imgs/burger.jpg" class="cardimage">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card mb-3" style="max-width: 540px;">
                <div class="row g-0">
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h5 class="card-title cardtitle">Hamburguesa Royal</h5>
                            <p class="card-text carddescription">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                            <p class="card-text cardprice">S/10</p>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-2"><a href="https://wa.link/b1erbu"><i class="bi bi-whatsapp"
                                            style="font-size: 30px; color: #00bb2d;"></i></a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-6"><button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Agregar al
                                        carrito</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <img src="assets/imgs/burger.jpg" class="cardimage">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-4">
            <div class="card mb-3" style="max-width: 540px;">
                <div class="row g-0">
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h5 class="card-title cardtitle">Hamburgesa bacon and cheese</h5>
                            <p class="card-text carddescription">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                            <p class="card-text cardprice">S/8</p>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-2"><a href="https://wa.link/b1erbu"><i class="bi bi-whatsapp"
                                            style="font-size: 30px; color: #00bb2d;"></i></a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-6"><button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Agregar al
                                        carrito</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <img src="assets/imgs/burger.jpg" class="cardimage">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card mb-3" style="max-width: 540px;">
                <div class="row g-0">
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h5 class="card-title cardtitle">Hamburguesa Royal</h5>
                            <p class="card-text carddescription">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                            <p class="card-text cardprice">S/10</p>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-2"><a href="https://wa.link/b1erbu"><i class="bi bi-whatsapp"
                                            style="font-size: 30px; color: #00bb2d;"></i></a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-6"><button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Agregar al
                                        carrito</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <img src="assets/imgs/burger.jpg" class="cardimage">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div id="polloalabrasa" class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center" style="background: url(assets/banners/3.jpg);background-size:cover;height: 180px;background-position: center bottom">
        <div class="p-2 bd-highlight">
            <h3 class="menucategoriestitle">Pollos a la brasa</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <h1>Pollos a la brasa</h1>
        <div class="col-4">
            <div class="card mb-3" style="max-width: 540px;">
                <div class="row g-0">
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h5 class="card-title cardtitle">Pollo Entero</h5>
                            <p class="card-text carddescription">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                            <p class="card-text cardprice">S/40</p>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-2"><a href="https://wa.link/b1erbu"><i class="bi bi-whatsapp"
                                            style="font-size: 30px; color: #00bb2d;"></i></a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-6"><button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Agregar al
                                        carrito</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <img src="assets/imgs/chicken.jpg" class="cardimage">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card mb-3" style="max-width: 540px;">
                <div class="row g-0">
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h5 class="card-title cardtitle">Cuarto de pollo</h5>
                            <p class="card-text carddescription">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                            <p class="card-text cardprice">S/16</p>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-2"><a href="https://wa.link/b1erbu"><i class="bi bi-whatsapp"
                                            style="font-size: 30px; color: #00bb2d;"></i></a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-6"><button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Agregar al
                                        carrito</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <img src="assets/imgs/chicken.jpg" class="cardimage">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-4">
            <div class="card mb-3" style="max-width: 540px;">
                <div class="row g-0">
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h5 class="card-title cardtitle">Pollo broaster</h5>
                            <p class="card-text carddescription">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                            <p class="card-text cardprice">S/55</p>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-2"><a href="https://wa.link/b1erbu"><i class="bi bi-whatsapp"
                                            style="font-size: 30px; color: #00bb2d;"></i></a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-6"><button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Agregar al
                                        carrito</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <img src="assets/imgs/chicken.jpg" class="cardimage">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card mb-3" style="max-width: 540px;">
                <div class="row g-0">
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h5 class="card-title cardtitle">Cuarto pollo broaster</h5>
                            <p class="card-text carddescription">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                            <p class="card-text cardprice">S/18</p>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-2"><a href="https://wa.link/b1erbu"><i class="bi bi-whatsapp"
                                            style="font-size: 30px; color: #00bb2d;"></i></a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-6"><button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Agregar al
                                        carrito</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <img src="assets/imgs/chicken.jpg" class="cardimage">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-4">
            <div class="card mb-3" style="max-width: 540px;">
                <div class="row g-0">
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h5 class="card-title cardtitle">Octavo de pollo</h5>
                            <p class="card-text carddescription">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                            <p class="card-text cardprice">S/12</p>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-2"><a href="https://wa.link/b1erbu"><i class="bi bi-whatsapp"
                                            style="font-size: 30px; color: #00bb2d;"></i></a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-6"><button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Agregar al
                                        carrito</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <img src="assets/imgs/chicken.jpg" class="cardimage">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card mb-3" style="max-width: 540px;">
                <div class="row g-0">
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h5 class="card-title cardtitle">Octavo pollo broaster</h5>
                            <p class="card-text carddescription">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                            <p class="card-text cardprice">S/14</p>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-2"><a href="https://wa.link/b1erbu"><i class="bi bi-whatsapp"
                                            style="font-size: 30px; color: #00bb2d;"></i></a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-6"><button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Agregar al
                                        carrito</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <img src="assets/imgs/chicken.jpg" class="cardimage">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>      
    
</div>
```

Comment: We can't really help you if you don't put all your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a white space on the right because your principalbanner row isn’t inside a container. Usually, the container *contains* the row, so the row fits the width of the display. Because you’re missing the container, your row is now wider than the display.

You can tell if something is too wide if there’s a horizontal scrollbar at the bottom of the browser window (I suspect there’s a horizontal scrollbar on your browser, but the image you provided is cutting off the bottom of the window).

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar sticky-top navbar-dark" style="
padding-top: 0px;" id="navbarprincipal">
    <div class="container-fluid navbarsubtitle" style="background-color: #0f1924;">
        <div class="d-flex align-items-center align-items-stretch">
            <div class="d-flex p-2 bd-highlight"><a class="schedule">Horario de atención: 9:00 a.m - 8:00 p.m</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class=" container-fluid" style="padding-bottom: 8px;">
        <div class="col-2">
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
                <div class="p-2 bd-highlight ">
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                        <img src="assets/logo.png" alt="" width="" height="" class="d-inline-block align-text-top">
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="col-8">
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
                <div class="p-2 bd-highlight "><a class="active">Carta</a></div>
                <div class="p-2 bd-highlight "><a class="headerelement">Ubicanos</a></div>
                <div class="p-2 bd-highlight "><a class="headerelement">¡Siguenos!</a></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-2">
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
                <div class="p-2 bd-highlight "><i class="bi bi-person" style="font-size: 30px; color: white;" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="bottom" title="Iniciar Sesión"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="p-2 bd-highlight "><i class="bi bi-bag" style="font-size: 30px; color: white;" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="bottom" title="Carrito de compras"></i>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row principalbanner align-items-center">
        <div class="entregadiv" style="margin-bottom: 25px;">
            <div class="col-12" style="margin-top: 20px;">
                <h3 style="color: black;">¿Como quieres tu pedido</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
            <div class="col-12">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col ">
                        <div class="col dropdownelement">
                            <i class="bi bi-bicycle" style="font-size: 30px; color: black;"></i>
                            <p style="color: black;">Delivery</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col ">
                        <div class="dropdownelement">
                            <i class="bi bi-cursor-fill" style="font-size: 30px; color: black;"></i>
                            <p style="color: black;">Retirar</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-12" style="margin-top: 10px;margin-bottom: 25px;">
                <input type="email" class="form-control " id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Ingresa tu dirección*">
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

I’ve revised your code to have `container-fluid` around your `principalbanner row.` To see the effect of the container, you can open the snippet full-screen and use your browser’s developer tools to turn off all of the attributes for the container. Then a scrollbar will appear at the bottom of the browser window with 24px of space on the right.

Comment: Thank you so much, you're a lifesaver